# Formatting a cell for a check mark if date is in another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I want to create a column that displays a check mark if a date is found in another column.  How do I write a formula in the check mark column to look in another cell and if date appears in that cell then a check mark appears in the column I created

Comment: What are you trying to check? If the column contains a specific date? If it contains any date? If it's any date, what other values can be in the column? Text? Numbers? Times? Will all the dates be in the future? The past? Both?

Answer (score 0):

you need to decide which Character you want to use for the check boxes, there are multiples to chose from. The formula would be for example:

`=IF(<your cell with the date>="","☒","☑")`

Google for 'unicode character for checkbox' to find alternatives if you don't like these two.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty unclear.

---

#### If the column can hold a date or nothing

If you need to check for a specific date

```
IF(B1="1/1/1990","✓")
```

If you need to check that it's just not empty

```
IF(B1<>"","✓")
```

If you need to check that a date is in the future

```
IF(B1>TODAY(),"✓")
```

---

#### If the column can hold a date or text

If you need to check that the cell holds a date when it can only hold a date or text -

```
=IF(ISERROR(DATEVALUE(F3)),"","✓")
```

---

#### If the column can hold a date or any number

If you need to check that a cell holds a date when it's possible that the cell holds any other type of number, well, we get into trouble.

You'll have to check the format of the cell using `=CELL(format)` [documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CELL-function-51bd39a5-f338-4dbe-a33f-955d67c2b2cf). As you see from the table you'd need to check arguments D1, D2, D3, D4 for date format. To excel, a date is a number and a number is a date.

```
IF(Cell("format",B1)="D4", "✓")
```